# Django, makemigrations doesn't detect model changes

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and I am using this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&t=912s

I created an app called `products` and I have it in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Upon creating a `Product` class in the `models.py` file in the products app folder, I created some fields such as `price`.

However, when I tried to use the `makemigrations` command, no changes detected was reported.

**Folder Layout and Settings**

[image: folder layout and settings]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.TextField()
```

I checked if there were any issues with the `Product` class but there doesn't seem to be any as far as I can see, so I am at a loss as to why no changes were detected.

Comment: Please share *code*, not *images* of code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score -1):

Refer the table - djangomigrations .. if the entry is there for the makemigration file already in the table then trunckage and rerun makemigrations and then do migrate